# Laravel not passing 0 (zero) value in if else condition but pass null value

Tags: laravel, if-statement, null

laravel not passing 0 in else condition
i have this code.

```
@foreach ($indicators as $indicator)
  @php
    if (!empty($indicator->rating)) {
      $rating = json_decode($indicator->rating, true);
      $starsum = array_sum($rating);
      $overallrating = $starsum/count($rating);
    }
    else{
      $overallrating = 0;
    }
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not passing 0 in else condition"? Also, what is the actual output, and what is the expected output? Maybe read this: [How to ask SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i mean in code it have to pass zero (0) by else condition  else{ $overallrating = 0; }

Comment: where have you declared this variable?  ($overallrating)

Comment: @IjazAhmad, yeah i get that but please show more code around what you've already supplied.

Comment: @geertjanknapen what you need

Comment: @IjazAhmad What happens after the foreach? What should it do? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing?

Comment: @geertjanknapen it have to save a zero value but it save nothing'

Comment: Can you define what `$indicator->rating` is?

Comment: field name in indicator table

Comment: So you want $overallrating to be 0 if $indicator->rating? Is this correct? If yes you are only assigning the $overallrating to 0, where do you print it out/use it?

Comment: @workservice but i need if condition code also

Comment: I didn't say you don't need the if, but we cannot tell with the code you have provided, you only assign it there, need the code where you return it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $indicator->rating express a relationship you can replace

```
if (!empty($indicator->rating))
```

with this code it is searching if the relation exists

```
if($indicator->rating()->exists())
```

or count the items

```
if($indicator->rating->count() > 0)
```

if it is a json field in the $indicator
you can first convert it to array and then check if not empty

```
$data = json_decode($indicator->rating, true);
if (!empty($data))
```